# magento: refresh php script in footer (called from footer block) upon each page load

Tags: php, magento

I have a footer block which calls a php script that generates random text.

It works great the first time but the footer appears to cache and so each page refresh or subsequent page loaded that uses the same footer shows the same generated text as the first.

How do I get Magento to reload that block and/or rerun the random script?

I've tried adding  but that didn't seem to work and even if it did, I don't want the refresh to be on a timed basis but rather on each page load/reload.

Thanks

Can I use session_cache_limiter() within the .phtml script?

**Update: I figured out that I can 'disable' the caching of 'Blocks HTML output' in the cache storage management page of the Magento Admin (CE 1.7). However, that disables caching of ALL blocks. Anyone know how to specifically disable caching of one specified block?

Answer (score 1):

A pragmatic solution is to feed the footer with an ajax call to some controller action which is not cached.